# How to export a React component as an embeddable script tag in vanilla HTML,CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine I have the following React Component

```
import { useEffect } from "react"

export default function AwesomeHelloWorld(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        let targetDiv = document.getElementById("hello-world-component-will-use-this-after-load");
        if (targetDiv) {
            //Do something with retrieved div
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>Hello World from a React Component</div>
    )
}
```

How can I build it into a single `helloworld.js` file such that someone can easily import the script into a regular html `<script/>` tag for use like this

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="./helloworld.js"/>
```

Then inside their html body, they will have a div that the generated script above will act on after page load like this

```
<div id="hello-world-component-will-use-this-after-load"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you see this?
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Yes I saw that, but that's not what I want because that will force my users to also embed  ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>```
  ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>```

Comment: In the example in that react site, I want my users to embed only   

```<script src="like_button.js"></script>``` and nothing more.

So, ```like_button.js``` should already have all the necessary react imports, and not forcing the imports on my users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating pure web component from react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970860/creating-pure-web-component-from-react-components)

Comment: @user15155716 since all of those are js files, having a webpack step to merge those files should solve the issue?